# How to stop redirect from partial page after form submit

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

Having an issue, I have a partialview named `Manage`, I load the partial in:

Controller `AdminPanel`, View `AdminProfile` like so:

```
                        <div id="tab-2" class="tab-pane">
                               @{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Account/Manage.cshtml");
                               }
                        </div>
```

When I click on save changes I get redirected to `/Account/Manage`, it should be `/AdminPanel/AdminProfile`?

[image]

Not sure if controller is returning the correct redirect or information for the json if I try to use a ajax script:

```
    public ActionResult Manage(ManageMessageId? message)
    {
        ViewBag.StatusMessage =
            message == ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess ? "Your password has been changed."
            : message == ManageMessageId.SetPasswordSuccess ? "Your password has been set."
            : message == ManageMessageId.RemoveLoginSuccess ? "The external login was removed."
            : "";
        ViewBag.HasLocalPassword = OAuthWebSecurity.HasLocalAccount(WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name));
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = Url.Action("Manage");
        return View();
    }
public ActionResult Manage(LocalPasswordModel model)
{
    bool hasLocalAccount = OAuthWebSecurity.HasLocalAccount(WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name));
    ViewBag.HasLocalPassword = hasLocalAccount;

            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = Url.Action("AdminProfile", "AdminPanel");
        //ViewBag.ReturnUrl = Url.Action("Manage");


    if (hasLocalAccount)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // ChangePassword will throw an exception rather than return false in certain failure scenarios.
            bool changePasswordSucceeded;
            try
            {
                changePasswordSucceeded = WebSecurity.ChangePassword(User.Identity.Name, model.OldPassword, model.NewPassword);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                changePasswordSucceeded = false;
            }

            if (changePasswordSucceeded)
            {
                    return RedirectToAction("AdminProfile", "AdminPanel", new { Message = ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess });
                
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The current password is incorrect or the new password is invalid.");
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // User does not have a local password so remove any validation errors caused by a missing
        // OldPassword field
        ModelState state = ModelState["OldPassword"];
        if (state != null)
        {
            state.Errors.Clear();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                WebSecurity.CreateAccount(User.Identity.Name, model.NewPassword);
                return RedirectToAction("AdminProfile", "AdminPanel", new { Message = ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess });
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", String.Format("Unable to create local account. An account with the name \"{0}\" may already exist.", User.Identity.Name));
            }
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    //return PartialView("Manage", model);
    return Json(new { redirectTo = Url.Action("AdminProfile", "AdminPanel") });
}
```

This is the partial page that is loaded:

```
 @model LocalPasswordModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Change Password";
}
<section class="hgroup">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>
        <ul class="breadcrumb pull-right top-right">
            <li>You're logged in as <strong>@User.Identity.Name</strong></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="message-success">@ViewBag.StatusMessage</ul>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Manage", "Account", Form.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary()
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Old Password</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.OldPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
            </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">New Password</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.NewPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Confirm Password</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Change password" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

        }
    </div>
</section>
```

The script below is placed in the `_LayoutPage` however as mentioned in the comments it is not doing anything.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("Manage", "Account")',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.redirectTo) {
                    // The operation was a success on the server as it returned
                    // a JSON objet with an url property pointing to the location
                    // you would like to redirect to => now use the window.location.href
                    // property to redirect the client to this location
                    window.location.href = result.redirectTo;
                } else {
                    // The server returned a partial view => let's refresh
                    // the corresponding section of our DOM with it
                    $(".tab-2").html(result);
                }
            },
            error: function () {
    
            }
        });
    </script>
```

All I am trying to do is stop the redirect after I submit, I have opened this to a bounty. It would be nice if you could also include how I could recieve the status messages back aswell after a user hits submit.

For instance user hits save changes > saves to the server > messages are then sent back to the partial page (all without redirecting)

Comment: It does not look as if your `$ajax()` call is attached to any DOM event.

Comment: Use `$.ajax()` _or_ `Ajax.BeginForm()` but not both. If you use `$.ajax()` convert your `Ajax.BeginForm()` to `Html.BeginForm()`.

Comment: Generally, we use AJAX when we _don't_ want to redirect. A standard form post might make your problem go away. Why have you decided to use AJAX here?

Comment: I cannot see anywhere that you have called the AJAX function on form submit. Also the ajax code has not been wrapped inside a function.

Comment: Decorate your post action with `[HttpPost]` and use `Ajax.BeginForm()`, as suggested by @yvette and @lewis-taylor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, you need to decorate your `POST` action result as a post.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Manage(LocalPasswordModel model){
```

Secondly, you can get rid of the javascript altogether by 
testing the validity of the form submit result within your controller 
and this will manage whether the user is redirected or not.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Manage(LocalPasswordModel model){

    if(condition to redirect){
        return RedirectToAction("AdminProfile", "AdminPanel");
    }
    return View(model);

}
```

Lastly, I cannot see where you've actually put you jquery. 
It needs to be put at the end of your form page, in your script section. 
You mention it's in your layout page?

I think this link may also help, [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/), also [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) is also useful to prevent form submission client side.

To control specifically where you want to redirect to, add redirects at every place there is a result, example: *please note I am only returning to the adminprofile as this is what the op wants*

```
if (changePasswordSucceeded)
{
    return RedirectToAction("AdminProfile", "AdminPanel", new { Message = ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess });

 }
 else
 {
     ModelState.AddModelError("", "The current password is incorrect or the new password is invalid.");
     return RedirectToAction("AdminProfile", "AdminPanel");
 }
```

As a sidenote, you need to think through your program flow to decide how you want to manage invalid attempts, etc.

Comment: Actually I realised the ajax script was doing nothing it was my redirect that was sending me back.

Comment: I seem to get redirected back to Account/Manage when I dont enter the correct credentials.

Comment: Redirect works fine if the correct credentials are inputted by the user however as soon as you hit submit with the wrong values or no values it sends me to Account/Manage. Also the messages arent being displayed in the partial. They are only displayed in Account/Manage.

Comment: Not now no. I need the messages sent back and rendered in the partial which is in AdminPanel/AdminProfile. Part of the profile has a tab called account, where you can change credentials. This tab renders the partial view. I dont want it redirecting to the Account/Manage page any more. I thought it would be fine just calling a partial but for some reason its an eroneous task.

Answer (score 2):

Is it because when you press save its doing a regular http post to the server to the Account/Manage page so you are being redirected. So your javascript is never actually running?

try using Ajax.BeginForm or changing the save button to use your javascript.

Comment: if you put a breakpoint on the return statement in the controller is the correct json being returned? it that controller method even being called?

Comment: so either use the ajax.beginform or attach the javascript you have with the onclick of of the save button.

Answer (score 1):

If you are posting your form data using AJAX then simply in the submit function

```
<form onsubmit="mysubmitfunc(event)" ....>
```

And in the submit function

```
function mysubmitfunc(e)
{
e.preventDefault();
/*
YOUR AJAX CODE GOES HERE
*/

return false; //last line in the function
}
```

Comment: Please don't recommend to people to put strings in `onsubmit` properties. Properly attach the function via javascript in the DOM ready event.

Comment: well, the main focus was on preventDefault and return false things rather than how to attach submit event. Yes, Its good approach to attach event through javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Use ajax submit in the right way, how? attach to form submission event, catch submit event, stop the post, post it from javscript, and process the response at success.

Replace your _LayoutPage js with next, make sure you are using ID to identify the form, if not this javascript may affect other forms.

```
$(function() { //shorthand document.ready function

    //recommended to use Id on form identification not class... search on google how to
    //attach handler on form submit
    $('.form-horizontal').submit(catchSubmit);


    //custom handler for form submit
    function catchSubmit(event) {
      event.preventDefault(); //stop html form post
      // ajax post with serialized form
      $.post($(this).attr("action"),
         $(this).serialize(),
         postSuccessHandler
      );
    }

   //redirect decizion
   function postSuccessHandler(data) {
     if (data.redirectTo) {
               window.location.href = data.redirectTo;
            } else {                    
                $(".tab-2").html(data);
            }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also move the html button to outside of the form.